# get all product list return with entry array list inside of product

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have done a get all product api.but it returning like blow. please correct me ,what did i wrong ?

My repository code:

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> FetchProductListAsync(
         Guid? itemId)
        {

            var feedOptions =
                  new FeedOptions
                  {
                      MaxItemCount = -1,
                      EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true
                  };

            var query =
                $"SELECT product FROM catalog join industry in catalog.Industy join category in industry.Category join product in category.Subcategory.Product where catalog.id ='" + itemId + "'";

            var queryDefinition =
                new SqlQuerySpec(query);

            var orderDocumentQuery =
                 _cosmosClient.CreateDocumentQuery<Product>(
                     UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(
                         _azureCosmosDbOptions.Value.DatabaseId, "catalog"), queryDefinition, feedOptions)
                     .AsDocumentQuery();

            var childrenSqlQuery = _cosmosClient.CreateDocumentQuery(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_azureCosmosDbOptions.Value.DatabaseId, "catalog"), query).AsDocumentQuery();
            var result = await childrenSqlQuery.ExecuteNextAsync();
            if (result.Any())
            {
                if (result.FirstOrDefault() != null)
                {
                    var countObj = result.FirstOrDefault();

                }
            }

            var orderList =
                new List<Product>();

            while (orderDocumentQuery.HasMoreResults)
            {
                orderList.AddRange(
                    await orderDocumentQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<Product>());
                Console.WriteLine(orderList);
            }

            return orderList;
        }
```

Actual input return addons and method of preparation   as null. 
Actual Output:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "12a22f6a-c75a-4622-b2ae-819714737147",
    "hasMethodOfPreparation": false,
    "methodOfPreparation": null,
    "addons": null
  }
]
```

But i need full array to return like blow
Expected output:

```
[
                            {
                                "Id": "d8ca2be8-845e-4f3b-854a-fdd10653a2ce",

                                "MethodOfPreparation": [
                                    {
                                        "id": "6eac1ea7-0d71-4181-a7b5-8a034b1922c3",
                                    }
                                ],
                                "Addons": [
                                    {
                                        "id": "72902f16-2a39-44bc-987b-4e17fc0756fc"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
```

How to solve this . For example i need to get all product for a catalog id.

Comment: In general, with SQL, you're going to have to join the relationships, and then project them into the right object graph once you get the results back. Given you're using CosmosDB, though, there may be a better way, but you'll need to consult the documentation for that. You also might consider using EF Core, which can work with CosmosDB. That will make queries like this trivial.

Comment: Can you please give me some more information. i am not understand

Comment: Can you provide a generic example of the structure of the document in CosmosDB? It is hard to debug the query without knowing the structure of what you are querying.